# Call a query (controller action) inside views

Tags: html, mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, controller

I am trying to create a table that mostly displays the numbers of each respective field by date. I only have one model for this one

View:

```
<table class="table-table-verif">
      <thead class="fixed_headers">
      <tr id = "thead-title">
        <th>Date</th>
        <th># True Positive</th>
        <th># True Negative</th>
        <th># False Positive</th>
        <th># False Negative</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
       <% @verification.each do |s| %>
        <tr id="thead-value">
          // what to do here?
        </tr>
       <% end %>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

I want to call these queries in my controller.

Controller:

```
  def date
    @verification = Verification.group(:Date).where("Findings = ? or Findings = ?", 'False Positive','False Negative').order(Date: :asc).count
  end

  def number_true_positive
    Verification.group(Date).where("Findings = ?", 'True Positive').order(Date: :asc).count
  end

  def number_false_positive
    Verification.group(:Date).where("Findings = ?", 'False Positive').order(Date: :asc).count
  end

  def number_true_negative
    Verification.group(:Date).where("Findings = ?", 'True Negative').order(Date: :asc).count
  end

  def number_false_negative
    Verification.group(:Date).where("Findings = ?", 'False Negative').order(Date: :asc).count
  end
```

Every column should count the number of respective records, and put the number on their respective `<th>` based on their date.

What is a better way to approach?

Comment: Write those queries on the `helper` method.

Comment: *Controller* is a bad place to put those *methods*. You should move them to *model* instead.

Comment: why you `order`ing it if you just need count?

Comment: @Md.FarhanMemon because I was using .group and I want to display the result base on dates and in ascending order.

Comment: @Emu how would I implement this? I mean how would I call helper method to views?

Comment: @Aurb you are calling `.count` on every query and it doesn't matter in which `order` it is, result remains same.

Comment: @Emu yes, there are different queries on every <th>, how would I call every helper method in views?

Comment: @Aurb, In this case the answer given by Memon is great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see lots of duplication in your code, you can create [`scopes`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes) for each subquery and can have multiple combinations.

In your `verification.rb`,

```
scope :date_grouped, -> { group(:Date) }

scope :falsy, -> { where("Findings = ? or Findings = ?", 'False Positive','False Negative') }

scope :truthy, -> { where("Findings = ? or Findings = ?", 'True Positive','True Negative') }

scope :findings_by, -> (value) { where(Findings: value) }

scope :date_asc, -> { order(Date: :asc) }
```

Now you can just call them as required.

e.g.

```
<%= Verification.date_grouped.falsy.date_asc %>
<%= Verification.date_grouped.truthy.date_asc %>
<%= Verification.date_grouped.findings_by('True Positive').date_asc %>
```

Comment: I'm not yet familiar with scopes, will read the documentation for it. Thanks for the suggestion, will try this one :)

Comment: I already set up all my necessary scope, how would I implement this on my view(calling them)?

Comment: the e.g section are the calls you have to make to get the result, check update

Comment: yay thanks! I kind of got it working now, but currently, it is only being displayed in one row, I think the query is being called on the column where the query was called. How can I do like, list first all the dates, then count the existence of the record of each date? Anyways, thanks a lot for helping me out :)